# Automatically align edge labels left or right in forest

Tags: macros, forest

I was trying to get edge labels to automatically appear to the left or the right of edges, depending on whether the corresponding node in the tree was a left or a right daughter. When I insert the code manually it works, but when I write a macro for it, I get an error message ('I do not know the key '/tikz/if n', to which you passed [...] and I am going to ignore it.') This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\newcommand{\edgelab}[1]{if n=1{edge label={node[midway,left]{#1}}}{edge label={node [midway, right]{#1}}}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{forest}
[S
    [A, if n=1{edge label={node[midway,left]{a}}}{edge label={node [midway, right]{b}}}]
    [B, \edgelab{b}]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The definition of \edgelab should - apart from the argument - be identical to the code I put after the A node (because I copypasted it.) This is my output:

[image]

So, what did I do wrong? (And, if you know, is there a way to put the if-clause within the node[]?)

Edit: Made my code more clearly reflect that I want to be able to give the edges individual labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write a *style*, a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  edgelab/.style={if n=1{edge label={node[midway,left]{#1}}}{edge label={node [midway, right]{#1}}}}
}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{forest}
[S
    [A, if n=1{edge label={node[midway,left]{a}}}{edge label={node [midway, right]{b}}}]
    [B, edgelab=b]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you know why it isn't possible to do the same with \newcommand? Shouldn't it behave the same as if I simply wrote that code wherever I use it?

Comment: The answer lies in the details of how `pgfkeys` works. While your macro gets expanded, pgfkeys thinks it's a key name (it searches for `=` before the expansion). For instructions on how to use pgfkeys, see section 82 of PGF manual.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping I could get away without learning how to do pgf and tikz :) Thanks for forest anyways, it's a great package (powerful while letting you do the basics without having a clue how the thing works)!