Separate nodes in tikz latex
I want to draw this tree in Latex. It is a graph of a structural proof for some code. 
I have tried
\node [draw, circle] {1}
       child { node [draw, circle] {2}
            child{ node [draw,circle] {3}
                child { node [draw,circle] {4} }
                child{ node [draw,circle] {5} }
            }
            child{ node [draw,circle] {6} 
                child{ node [draw,circle] {7} }
                child{ node [draw,circle] {8} 
                    child{ node [draw,circle] {9} }
                    child{ node [draw,circle] {10} }
                }
            }
        };

but nodes 5 and 7 collapse. Like it is seen

Furthermore, how can I link them all to number 11?

Have a look at the forest package

Since this is not formally a tree, forest or the base TikZ tree methods are probably not the best tool. The TikZ graph drawing methods or the tkz-graph package are probably a better bet.  If it's a one-off drawing, then you could probably do it fastest with just a matrix of nodes.

Although if you're doing a lot of these kinds of graphs, forest is not the best tool, it's not to difficult to use it to draw this specific graph. So whether it's the best tool for the job may depend on how many of them you need to draw.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
% edgelab style adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319395/2693
\forestset{circled/.style={draw,circle,align=center},
blank/.style={draw=none,no edge,align=center},
  edgelab/.style={if n=1{edge label={node[midway,left]{V}}}{if n=2{}{edge label={node [midway, right]{F}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}for tree={circled}
[1,
[2,name=2,for descendants=edgelab [3
     [4,name=4,][R2,blank] [5,name=5] ] 
   [R1,blank]
   [6,name=6 
     [7,name=7]
     [R3,blank]
     [8
        [9,name=9][R4,blank] [10,name=10]
     ]
   ]
]]
\node[draw,circle,  below= 4cm of 2] (11) {11};
\node[draw=none,above right =.5cm and -1cm of 6]{R5};
\foreach \x in {4,5,7,9,10}{
\draw (11) -- (\x);
};
\end{forest}
\end{document}



I'd use forest, even though it isn't the best option, or a matrix of nodes. However, here's my attempt with the graphdrawing library. I periodically revisit TikZ's graphs, struggle to make sense of it, and eventually return to other methods. So I recommend it, but only to those, unlike myself, who are capable of understanding it.
In this case, I can't figure out how to align things without additional coordinates and I can't figure out how to get the 7 to go left of the 8 regardless. I also didn't manage to get all the labels to look neat, though I did finally succeed in getting only 'proper' nodes circled.
Three graphs: the first unlabelled, the second with node labels added and the third with edge labels as well.
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/717576/
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[layered layout, components go right top aligned,  nodes={circle,draw,minimum size=4ex,inner sep=0pt,font=\sffamily}] {
    1 -- { 2 --
      {  
        3 -- {  4 -- 4a[coordinate] , 5 -- 5a[coordinate] }  -- 11  ,
        6 -- { 7 -- 11, 8 -- { 9, 10 } -- 11 }  
      }
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.append style={text=orange,font=\sffamily}]
  \graph[layered layout, components go right top aligned, sibling distance=15mm,  nodes={circle,draw,minimum size=4ex,inner sep=0pt,font=\sffamily}] {
    1 -- { 2 --
      {  
        3[label=right:R1] -- {  4[label=right:R2] -- 4a[coordinate] , 5[label=right:R2] -- 5a[coordinate] }  -- 11  ,
        6[label=45:R5] -- { 7[label=-45:R3] -- 11, 8 -- { 9[label=right:R4], 10 } -- 11 }  
      }
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={font=\sffamily,blue}  ,every label/.append style={text=orange},draw=blue]
  \graph [layered layout, components go right top aligned, sibling distance=15mm, nodes={circle,draw,minimum size=4ex,inner sep=0pt,font=\sffamily}]{
    1 -- { 
      2 -- ["V"'draw=none] 3[label=right:R1] -- {  4[label=right:R2] -- 4a[coordinate] , 5[label=right:R2] -- 5a[coordinate] }  -- 11;  
      2 -- ["F"] {
        6[label=45:R5] --["V"]  7[label=-45:R3] -- 11;
        6 -- ["F"] {
          8 --["V"] 9[label=right:R4] -- 11;
          8 --["F"] 10  -- 11 
        }
      }
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




[Image quality is not great ....]
